# Base Internationalization in OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, localization

Does Base Internationalization work on OSX 10.7 (with 10.7 sdk) or it's only for 10.8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW145) 10.8 only.

from **Xcode 4.4. Release Notes**:
*The Use Base Internationalization setting in the project editor works only on Mac products for deployment on OS X v.10.8 and later. Xcode must also be running on OS X v.10.8 or later.*